# IE7 jQuery 1.9.1 issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

In only IE7, the script error message shows-up in the status bar, which cripples the UI. For example, if I click on any of the anchor tags, it doesn't work. By the way, this script error location and callstack was taken using the Web Development Helper for IE7.

If I include **jquery-1.9.1.min.js**, in IE7 I see the following script error messages:

```
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [4]
    wt
    code: if(t=i.find.ID(u.matches[0].replace(et,tt),t)[0],!t) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [4]
    st
    code: return wt(e.replace(W,"$1"),t,n,r) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [4]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: b.find(e,this[t],n) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return!n||n.jquery?(n||r).find(e):this.constructor(n).find(e) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js [2]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return t&&"string"==typeof t&&!e.isPlainObject(n)&&(o=y.exec(t))&&o[1]&&("<"!==t.charAt(0)&&r("$(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character"),n&&n.context&&(n=n.context),e.parseHTML)?v.call(this,e.parseHTML(e.trim(t),n,!0),n,a):v.apply(this,arguments) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return new b.fn.init(e,t,r) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [124]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: $("#IPL a").click(function()  {
            self.dropdownTools.hide();
        }) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [10]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: this.attachEvents() at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [270]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: var nwtTools = new NWTTools() at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: if(u[a].apply(t[0],t[1])===!1&&e.stopOnFalse) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return t=t||[],t=[e,t.slice?t.slice():t],!u||i&&!l||(n?l.push(t):c(t)),this at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: b.isReady=!0,e!==!0&&--b.readyWait>0||(n.resolveWith(o,[b]),b.fn.trigger&&b(o).trigger("ready").off("ready")) at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [3]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: (o.addEventListener||"load"===e.type||"complete"===o.readyState)&&(q(),b.ready())
```

If I include **jquery-1.9.1.js**, in IE7 I see the following script error messages:

```
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [5472]
    select
    code: context = Expr.find["ID"]( token.matches[0].replace( runescape, funescape ), context )[0]
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [3998]
    Sizzle
    code: return select( selector.replace( rtrim, "$1" ), context, results, seed )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [5576]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: jQuery.find( selector, this[ i ], ret )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [196]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return ( context || rootjQuery ).find( selector )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js [2]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return t&&"string"==typeof t&&!e.isPlainObject(n)&&(o=y.exec(t))&&o[1]&&("<"!==t.charAt(0)&&r("$(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character"),n&&n.context&&(n=n.context),e.parseHTML)?v.call(this,e.parseHTML(e.trim(t),n,!0),n,a):v.apply(this,arguments)
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [62]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [124]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: $("#IPL a").click(function()  {
            self.dropdownTools.hide();
        })
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [10]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: this.attachEvents()
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [270]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: var nwtTools = new NWTTools()
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [1037]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: if ( list[ firingIndex ].apply( data[ 0 ], data[ 1 ] ) === false && options.stopOnFalse )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [1148]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: fire( args )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [433]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [103]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: jQuery.ready()
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [124]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: $("#IPL a").click(function()  {
            self.dropdownTools.hide();
        })
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [10]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: this.attachEvents()
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/nwtTools.js [270]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: var nwtTools = new NWTTools()
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [1037]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: if ( list[ firingIndex ].apply( data[ 0 ], data[ 1 ] ) === false && options.stopOnFalse )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [1148]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: fire( args )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [433]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] )
at http://10.15.1.77:8080/mhs/3p/jquery-1.9.1.js [103]
    JScript anonymous function
    code: jQuery.ready()
```

Comment: Those are not error messages, they're stack traces. What are the reported errors?

Comment: You're first problem is using jQuery >=1.73 for IE7 compatibility. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you might wanna read their change-logs and forums. If you're wanting Compat jQuery with ANY IE before 8 (before they tried to integrate CSS3 and HTML4.1 standards) you're going to have a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: Also, take note, Basic Support for IE7 ends next year, Extended support is ending in 2017, and IE7 should be completely flushed by 2020, according to MS Support Forums.

Comment: See [this page](http://jquery.com/download/) Where jQuery even tells you bad support for IE. What they dont tell you on that page (old site used too, dunno why they havn't corrected it) is that, IE8 can handle most of the changes from jQuery 1.73 to <1.9, but IE 7 is better with 1.6x and below, while IE6 is best with 1.4x and below

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you can always use `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` type comments to load dif jQuery libs based on IE version. This means having different JS files too tho, at least for specific content. Namely the functions that wont transverse all jQuery Versions and/or Browser versions. [More Info on Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Where exactly within **Your code** does the error happen?

Comment: @SpYk3HH Where does it say jQuery has less support for IE7 in recent versions? All it says is jQuery 2.0 does not support IE6/7/8, but jQuery 1.9 and on does and will continue to do so until demand for it is gone. In this case he is correctly including 1.9.1 which has full support for IE7.

Comment: It said it on the old doc page, and I'm speaking from years of experoence with jQuery with cross browser support

Comment: I tried jQuery 1.7.2, the errors go away in IE7. Now I'm thinking about using 1.7 for IE7 and 1.9 for all the others. How can I achieve this? How can I load diff jQuery versions based on the browser type?

Comment: It's quite easy. I used conditions to include jQuery for IE 7 and the other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used jquery 1.7.2 for IE7 and jquery 1.9.1 for all the other browsers. It works fine now. Thanks to SpYk3HH.

Comment: I was wondering if there's any way to include a specific jquery lib only for ff3.6.